# Правильно ли поставленны знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

"В сфере медицинского страхования Компания занимает 40% всех застрахованных граждан Украины, это – более 460 тысяч человек".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не нужно тире, запятая стоит на месте.

Comment: Спасибо, Элен! Возможно правильней будет написать "В сфере медицинского страхования Компания занимает 40% всех застрахованных граждан Украины - это более 460 тысяч человек"?

Comment: На мой взгляд, запятая здесь уместнее.